# Issue with my XML file in Java Apache Tomcat v7.0

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Hey guys so I am trying to get my form sent to a class file within src/'where the packages are located'.  I'm getting issues because if I am on the form page which is contained in a WebContent folder the url is...`http://localhost:8080/Final_Project/Band_roster.jsp` Once I hit submit it gets sent to the class file and sends it to this url. `http://localhost:8080/bandser` This url just does not look right?  So once it is sent here I get a 404 error.  I am using a xml file to transfer over.

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>BandListServ</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>bandServ.BandListServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BandListServ</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/bandser</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error_404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error_java.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>BandForm.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the class file url in which it tells me once I hit properties `\workspace\finalprojectfor_client\src\BandListServ.java`.
So If you need more info let me know, I really appreciate the help!

EDIT:

also in the XML file I am getting an error saying - `Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but assuming your webapp is named Final_Project, the url to your servlet is missing that context. The url should be http://localhost:8080/Final_Project/bandser

Comment: Even that url does not work.

Comment: What I am asking is how to make this work so the info is sent to the class file once the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Well, based on your web.xml, you need to fix the url you are posting to. It should be the one in my original comment.

Comment: Even with changing it, it does not help.  Would it have to do anything with that error I am getting in the top of page?  Look at my edit in post.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your web.xml, so no. I'm not sure how you are deploying this. Are you using an IDE? Are you deploying a war file? What is your servlet container?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21156/discussion-between-david-biga-and-rmlan)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I replaced javaee by j2ee and it worked.